# Adding a margin to the first and second div only

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I am looking to add a bottom margin of 10px to the first and second "page" div only. Should I add it to the page or page-block

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWYObw

```
<div class="rows first">
<div class="page">
<div class="page-block">
<div class="page-image"><a href="/cat1"><img alt="" src="mypic1.jpg"   style="width: 198px; height: 178px;"></a></div>

<div class="block-heading"><a href="/category1">category1</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="page">
<div class="page-block">
<div class="page-image"><a href="/cat2"><img alt="" src="mypic2.jpg"  style="width: 201px; height: 178px;"></a></div>

<div class="block-heading"><a href="/category2">category2</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="page">
<div class="page-block">
<div class="page-image"><a href="/cat3"><img alt="" src="mypic3.jpg"   style="width: 227px; height: 170px;"></a></div>

<div class="block-heading"><a href="/category3">category3</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="page last">
<div class="page-block">
<div class="page-image"><a href="/cat4"><img alt="" src="mypic4.jpg" style="width: 201px; height: 178px;"></a></div>

<div class="block-heading"><a href="/category4">category4</a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

So the cat1 and cat2 can have a gap added

Answer (score 4):

You can use `first-of-type` along with `+` which is adjacent selector. You can use `nth-of-type` as well for this.

```
.page:first-of-type,
.page:first-of-type + div.page {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5thvp1xL/)

`nth-of-type()` can be handy as well here,

```
.page:nth-of-type(1),
.page:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

There's another way you can achieve this, but I would suggest you to ignore because it is very much parent-child dependent.

```
.row > div:nth-of-type(1),
.row > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Is there a second-of-type, where you could select 2nd div?

Answer (score 1):

I think that

```
.page:nth-of-type(-n+2){
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Is the best way to achieve this. It's cleaner than

```
.page:nth-of-type(1), .page:nth-of-type(2){
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I like the second example for clarity and the first (despite it being slightly more obscure) for brevity. But, given that n starts at 1, shouldn't the first example read: .page:nth-of-type(-n+3) ?

Comment: @Rounin no that is not the case. N doesn't start at 1 here

Comment: Thanks for setting me straight, @Gust. For some reason, I thought that in CSS, `n` was 1-indexed (not sure where I got that idea from?!), but I stand corrected: `n` starts (always) at 0.  Thanks also for giving an example of using `-n` - I've never come across it before and I can see it has huge potential!

Comment: It sure has. You should check out [nthmaster](http://nthmaster.com/) for more tips on how to select elements in CSS. I see daily how most people write way too much code for a simple task CSS can do. CSS counters are, for example, widely unknown

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new class e.g here:

```
.with-bottop-margin {
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

and add this class along with page class to that `div`

Answer (score 0):

The following will also work: http://jsfiddle.net/5thvp1xL/1/

```
.page:nth-child(1), .page:nth-child(2) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```